# How to fix "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_create]_" elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am using Nodejs to index some data into Elasticsearch(hosted on kubernetes),I am using `client.create()` method to index document in Elasticsearch. If I run the code on localhost and kubernetes Elasticsearch endpoint, Everything is working fine. But after deploying the same code when I tried indexing a document, I am getting an error:

> "[invalid_type_name_exception] Document mapping type name can't start
>   with '_', found: [_create] :: {"path":"/index_name/_create/docId"]".

Elasticsearch version "6.3.0" and node_module version "^16.0.0".
Also, it was working initially but stopped working from past few days.
I think the issue is with some compatibility and configurations, can anyone please help?

I tried using client.index instead of client.create and it works fine.
i already matched all configuration and compatibility files on local and server. Everything seems OK to me.

```
const elasticsearchDoc = {
      index: "school",
      type: "_doc",
      id: 12345,
      body: { name:"raj",marks:40 }
};
const result = await client.create(elasticsearchDoc);
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the [old JS client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/index.html) library instead of [the new one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html).

With 16.0.0 you need [to explicitely set the `apiVersion` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/configuration.html#config-options) to the 6.x version because 7.0 is the default and that's probably why you're seeing this error (since you're using ES 6.3.0):

```
apiVersion: 6.7
```

Comment: But how it is working on localhost, because i am using same node_module version at both local and server

Comment: Are you sure you have the same ES version on local and server?

Comment: yes, 6.3.0 version.I am also sure that it is some configuration or compatibility issue, but i can't figure it out.

Comment: yes i got the solution, it was a node module version issue. i.e version compatibility  conflict. Thanks for your answer, it actually helped.

Comment: Included version worked for me.